# Quadratic equations confusion

Tags: quadratics

Well we know about quadratic equations, but quad means four, but quadratic equations have two roots.
So why is it so?

Comment: You surely wanted to ask for quadratic equations? or set theory?

Comment: Quadratic equations

Comment: then y does heading asks about set A?

Comment: Ooh sorry i forgot to change that

Comment: A quadratic equation contains a square. *Quadratus* is Latin for square.

Comment: Please upvote the question

Comment: @ShanimAkhtar That's not how voting works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadratic.html) says about quadratic equations.

> The Latin prefix quadri- is used to indicate the number 4, for example, quadrilateral, quadrant, etc. However, it also very commonly used to denote objects involving the number **2**. This is the case because **quadratum** is the Latin word for **square**, and since the area of a square of side length  **x** is given by $x^2$, a polynomial equation having exponent two is known as a ***quadratic*** ("**square-like**") equation. By extension, a quadratic surface is a *second-order algebraic surface*.

By analogy, since the volume of a cube of side length **x** is $x^3$, a polynomial equation having exponent three is called a **cubic** equation. An equation of degree four is then unimaginatively called a **quartic** equation, or sometimes (more commonly in older sources) a **biquadratic** equation.